# There are duplicate records in table, we need to select only the latest records as per date using group by or window function in sql

Tags: sql, database, group-by, window-functions

There are duplicate records in table, we need to select only the latest records as per date using group by or window function in sql

```
| emp_id | emp_name | department| create_date
+--------------------------------------------+
|   1    |  Nilesh  |    10     |  1-JAN-22  |
|   1    |  Nilesh  |    11     |  5-JAN-22  |
|   2    |  Rohit   |    12     |  1-JAN-22  | 
|   2    |  Rohit   |    13     |  5-JAN-22  |
```

code:

````
select * from (
    select emp_id, emp_name, create_date, department, row_number() over
        (partition by date(create_date) 
         order by create_date desc) as row_num 
    from emp1) 
where row_num = 1
order by create_date;```
````

Comment: Please share with us the code you have tried ? Also tag a database that you use. Is it Oralce or MySQL or SQLServer... ?

Comment: select *
from (
    select emp_id, emp_name, Create_date, department, row_number() over
        (partition by date(create_date) 
         order by Create_date desc) as row_num 
    from emp1) 
where row_num = 1
order by create_date;

Comment: Hi @SachinKangane great, now add that code to your question by editing your question. Also, add the database tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a `GROUP BY` like so

```
SELECT 
    emp_id, emp_name, department, MAX(create_date)
FROM 
    emp1
GROUP BY 
    emp_id, emp_name, department
```

If you want to use `ROW_NUMBER` you have to `PARTITION BY` the id

```
SELECT 
    emp_id, emp_name, department, create_date
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        emp_id, emp_name, department, create_date, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (partition by emp_id order by create_date desc) as num
    FROM 
        emp1
) sub_query
where num = 1
```